# Strange behaviour when implementing strcat in C

Tags: c, pointers, char, strcat

I'm trying to implement the strcat function myself. Here's my code:

```
char *my_strcat(char *dst, const char* src) {
    char *tmp = dst;
    while(*tmp) {
        tmp ++;
    }
    while(*tmp++ = *src++);
    return dst;
}
```

However, when I try to test this function, I get only the src string. (i.e. I'm expecting to get dst+src, but the returned value is the same as src)

As we can tell from the code, in the first while loop, I'm trying to move tmp pointer to the end of dst.
However,

1. I tried to add a printf in the first while loop, nothing is printed out, which indicates that it didn't even entered the loop.
2. Then I tried to used `if (*tmp == '\0') print something`, and found that `*tmp == '\0'` is true.

But I'm pretty sure that tmp is a non-empty string, so `*tmp` should point to the first character of the string (I think). So I'm feeling confused about it. Can anyone tell why this happens and how can I fix it?

Edit:
The calling code is

```
char *subpath = "";
subpath = my_strcat(subpath, path);
```

`path` is a `const char*` read from the command.
Do I need to assign the value back to subpath? Or just calling `my_strcat` is enough?

Comment: Show the code calling this. AFAICS, this code is okay.

Comment: Use a debugger to see what actually happens and, more importantly, *why*.

Comment: user13693348, Calling code is in error.  `my_strcat()` is OK.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I've edited the question and put the calling code in it :)

Comment: Names seem backwards.  I'd expect `my_strcat(path, subpath)`.

Comment: Beginner FAQ here: [Common string handling pitfalls in C programming](https://software.codidact.com/posts/284849). Your problem is FAQ #3.

Comment: @Lundin the FAQ helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here:

```
char *subpath = "";
subpath = my_strcat(subpath, path);
```

- subpath points to a string of length 0, there is not enough space to append anything.
- subpath points to a string literal and writing into string literals is undefined behaviour, on modern desktop platforms your program usually crashes.

You want something like this:

```
char subpath[100] = "";
char *foo;
foo = my_strcat(subpath, path);
```

or just

```
char subpath[100] = "";
my_strcat(subpath, path);
```

or

```
char subpath[100] = "Hello ";
my_strcat(subpath, "world!");
printf("%s\n", subpath);  // prints  Helllo World!
```

Comment: I've also tried `char *subpath = '\0'`, which yields an error when compiling. And `char *subpath = "\0"`, but got the same result.

Comment: oh! I'll try that

Comment: @user13693348 read the chapter dealing with strings in your C learning material. Everything about C strings and their specific aspects are explained there.

Comment: wow It works!! Thanks a lot!! I'm always confused about char[] and char * etc...

Comment: Detail: "and string literals cannot be written to." is more like "and writing to string literals is UB".  Writing _might_ "work".

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thanks for the suggestions :) I started from C++ and string is so convenient until I met this course work which doesn't support strings...

Comment: _"and string literals cannot be written to."_.  The problem is that sometimes they _can_ be written to.  It may be important here to introduce the concept of  _`UB`_ one more time.